# Android App Inventor Barcode Scanning

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, app-inventor

So I see there are a lot of questions regarding Barcode Scanning in Android applications, but this one is relating to Barcode Scanning in the App Inventor.

I followed a tutorial I found online to create a barcode scanning application where you press a button, it launches the scanner and then based on the results, the second button on the screen launches a URL with a passed variable through it. I developed the app myself in App Inventor so I could modify it to my needs, but I have encountered a problem. The barcode scanner launches, scans successfully (Product Found confirmation), but then upon returning to the main screen, the resultLabel.Text value is not changed and neither is the resultActionButton.Text value. Below is the block diagram of my application and a link to the tutorial I followed.

Thank you in advance!

Here is the block diagram image: 
[image: http://imm.io/3N60]

Link to tutorial: http://androidadvice.blogspot.com/2010/09/app-inventor-sample-project-barcode.html

Comment: Do you know if BarcodeScanner1.AfterScan is being reached?  To find out, you could add a "Notifier component":http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/learn/reference/components/other.html#Notifier and have it show an alert before the ifelse block.

Answer (score 0):

try to pass the data through a tinydb.
for instance, afterscan event > tinydb1.storevalue tag:resultLabel(desired_text) value to store: result
set resultLabel.text to tinydb1.getvalue tag: resultLabel(desired_text)
and notifier1.showalert text:launched afterscan activity; so that you know the event is getting called